# UMP Test for $f_{\theta}(x)=2\theta^{-2}(\theta-x)I_{(0,\theta)}(x)$

Tags: statistics, hypothesis-testing

I am trying to find the UMP test for the following question:

Let X be a sample of size 1 from a  Lebesgue pdf $f_{\theta}$. Find a UMP test of size $\alpha$  for

$$H_{o}:\theta=\theta_{0} \hspace{5mm}  H_{1}:\theta=\theta_{1}$$

when $$f_{\theta}(x)=2\theta^{-2}(\theta-x)I_{(0,\theta)}(x), \hspace{4mm} \theta_0<\theta_1$$

I propose the following test

$$T(X) = 
     \begin{cases}
       1  & \theta_0<X<\theta_1 \\ 
       \gamma &  X<\theta_0\\
     \end{cases}$$
where $\gamma=\alpha$ to get the desired size.

I reject $\theta=\theta_0$ with prob 1 when $\theta_0<X<\theta_1$ because it is not possible that our observation was produced from a r.v with $f_{\theta_0}$ distribution due to the support constraint. For the boundary randomization is required and therefore  since $X\sim f_{\theta_0}$ is a proper r.v then $P_{\theta_0}(X<\theta_0)=1$ and since $P_{\theta_0}(\theta_0<X<\theta_1)=0$ then  $\gamma=\alpha$ to get desired size. Is this correct?

Comment: Your test cannot depend on $\theta_1$ if it is UMP.

Comment: @StubbornAtom Why can't it depend on $\theta_1$?

Comment: Because UMP test is most powerful against every alternative in the class $\Theta_1$ of $H_1$, not just $\theta_1$. Have you tried applying Neyman-Pearson?

Comment: @StubbornAtom This is a simple hypothesis not a composite hypothesis

Comment: Theta is known the inequality is just letting is know that theta 1 is larger than theta 0

Comment: @StubbornAtom For the  Neymar Pearson Lemma, the objective is to partition the range of the random variable. if X lies is some region we reject if not accept the null.  For the notation $P(f_1(X)>kf_0(X))$ this is the same as $P(X\in \mathcal{R}:f_1(X)>kf_0(X))$. Am I correct in my understanding?

Comment: In Neyman-Pearson, you reject $H_0$ for large values of the ratio $f_1/f_0$. So the rejection region is $\{X: f_1/f_0\ge k\}$ for some constant $k$.

Comment: Okay my confusion was due to the mention of UMP for a simple alternative. I realised that you are simply looking for an MP test which is then trivially UMP. To see if your answer is correct, you can compare the powers of your test and the one in my answer at $\theta=\theta_1$. If they are equal then both tests are MP/UMP. Ignore previous comments.

Answer (score 1):

The alternative hypothesis is basically $H_1:\theta>\theta_0$. This is equivalently expressed as $H_1:\theta=\theta_1(>\theta_0)$ where $\theta_1$ is just an arbitrary value of $\theta$ under $H_1$. But as UMP test is most powerful against every possible alternative, your test cannot depend on the specific choice of $\theta_1$.

For $\theta_1>\theta_0$, you have

\begin{align}
\frac{f_{\theta_1}(x)}{f_{\theta_0}(x)}&=\left(\frac{\theta_0}{\theta_1}\right)^2\left(\frac{\theta_1-x}{\theta_0-x}\right)\frac{\mathbf1_{0<x<\theta_1}}{\mathbf1_{0<x<\theta_0}}
\\&=\begin{cases}
\left(\frac{\theta_0}{\theta_1}\right)^2\left(\frac{\theta_1-x}{\theta_0-x}\right) &,\text{ if }0<x<\theta_0
\\\infty &,\text{ if }\theta_0<x<\theta_1
\end{cases}
\end{align}

When $0<x<\theta_0<\theta_1$,

$$\frac{\theta_1-x}{\theta_0-x}=1+\frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{\theta_0-x}$$

And as $x$ increases, $\theta_0-x$ decreases, so that $\frac{\theta_1-\theta_0}{\theta_0-x}$  increases.

Therefore the ratio $f_{\theta_1}/f_{\theta_0}$ is increasing in $x$, which gives you a most powerful test using Neyman-Pearson lemma. Show that this test does not depend on $\theta_1$, which is then a UMP test by definition.

Alternatively, since $f_{\theta}$ has monotone likelihood ratio you can also apply Karlin-Rubin theorem directly.